What is the expected value of orbital angular momentum $$ in a octahedral crystal field, where 2 electrons occupy the $_{2}$ orbitals?
What is the expected value of the orbital angular momentum  for a regular octahedral crystal field, where only 2 electrons occupy the _2 orbitals? Since these orbitals are degenerate and the _2 manifold is not symmetrically filled (full symmetric filling occurs with 3 or 6 electrons), there is no complete quenching of the orbital momentum. How can I calculate the exact value of , given that we cannot directly apply Hund's rules?

based on the 4 group character table, it seems that the -electrons in the _2 states behave as if they were  p-electrons carrying  = 1. Does this imply that there is no quenching at all due to the degeneracy? Specifically, since the 4-fold symmetry only allows coupling between orbital momentum states _1 m and _2 ​ where _2 − _1 = 4 is never satisfied, does this mean there is no coupling and hence no quenching?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
